# Sharing images fails to load through intent

Tags: java, android

I have tried sharing the image to facebook, whatsapp, yahoo but none of them were able to load the image / attach image.

I have the following code :

```
File pictureFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

 Intent imageIntent = new Intent(
 imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 imageIntent.setType("image/*");
 imageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));

 PendingIntent shareIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, imageIntent, 0);
```

I have tried using Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()) and Uri.parse(pictureFile.getParent()) and also tried putting the bitmap instead, but none of these works. Please help me

Comment: Are you using `FileProvider`  ?

Comment: File what? the code is already posted

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FileProvider to generate the Uri for file -
`FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageName + ".fileprovider", file)`